# Search values from first column in html table using JS?

Tags: javascript, search, search-engine, html-table

I have this table

```
<th>Example No.</th>
<th>Column 1</th>
<tr>
<td id="SampleId">3512376894</td>
<td>two.test2@hotmail.com</td>
</tr>
```

I have script that search the values by all columns. But all I want to do is search the values by first column only with td id. But I don't know how to do that. Please kindly, help me to do that? Thanks!

[Here's the jsfiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/rjhxrb20/5/)

Here's the JScript:

```
function doSearch() {
        var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
        var targetTable = document.getElementById('dataTable');
        var targetTableColCount;
        for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
            var rowData = '';
            if (rowIndex == 0) {
                targetTableColCount = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.length;
                continue; //do not execute further code for header row.
            }
            for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < targetTableColCount; colIndex++) {
                rowData += targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).textContent;
                if (rowIndex <= 1) {
                    document.getElementById('noresults').style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the snippet below to search within a given column for a certain term.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<table id="dataTable">
  <th>Example No.</th>
  <th>Column 1</th>
  <th>Column  2</th>
  <tr>
    <td>345678917</td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>one_test1@gmail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3512376894</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>two.test2@hotmail.com</td>
  </tr>  
</table>

// JavaScript
window.onload = function(){
  var term = "3512376894";                   // term you're searching for
  var column = 0;                            // which column to search
  var pattern = new RegExp(term, 'g');       // make search more flexible 
  var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
  var tr = table.getElementsByTagName('TR');
  for(var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++){
    var td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('TD');
    for(var j = 0; j < td.length; j++){
      if(j == column && td[j].innerHTML == term){

      // for more flexibility use match() function and the pattern built above
      // if(j == column && td[j].innerHTML.match(pattern)){

        console.log('Found it: ' + td[j].innerHTML);
      }
    }    
  }
};
```

Output:

```
Found it: 3512376894
```

[Working jsBin](http://jsbin.com/qihuticepima/4/edit?html,js,output) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z82L1Lxu/) or this version [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z82L1Lxu/5/)

[Verions 4](http://jsfiddle.net/z82L1Lxu/1/) | 
[Verions 5](http://jsfiddle.net/z82L1Lxu/2/) | 
[Verions 6](http://jsfiddle.net/z82L1Lxu/5/)

Comment: Why are you looping through all of the cells to get at just one of them?

Comment: @JLRishe I know I could do the same using `[rows]` and `[cells]` collection but somehow I prefer this way. However, doesn't `[rows]` or `[cells]` work the same internally ;) And, yes, your solution is just fine as well.

Comment: I wasn't trying to suggest that you should use `rows` and `cells`. You can just use `td[column]` to get the desired cell and nix that inner `for` loop.

Comment: @User014019 `if(td[j].id == SampleId && td[j].innerHTML == term)`

Comment: @User014019 `var term = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;` check the new [jsBIn](http://jsbin.com/gawomabezina/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @User014019 Try this one [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/yepinixoqula/1/edit?html,js,output) What browser you're using? Just in case...

Comment: @User014019 If you have a new question, please ask a new question. Don't change your current question. Also, it's not legal for two elements to have the same ID, so it's not a valid requirement.

Comment: @hex494D49 here's the link of follow-up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560646/follow-up-of-how-to-search-values-from-first-column-in-html-table-using-pure-nat

Comment: @hex494D49 Here's how you can do this with the same approach but without the inner `for` loop: http://jsfiddle.net/84614g3r/ It makes absolutely no sense to use nested `for` loops for this, and being complacent with it just because you got an error message on your first attempt will just leave you with sloppy code.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this is what you want to do:

```
function findRows(table, column, searchText) {
    var rows = table.rows,
        r = 0,
        found = false,
        anyFound = false;

    for (; r < rows.length; r += 1) {
        row = rows.item(r);
        found = (row.cells.item(column).textContent.indexOf(searchText) !== -1);
        anyFound = anyFound || found;

        row.style.display = found ? "table-row" : "none";
    }

    document.getElementById('noresults').style.display = anyFound ? "none" : "block";
}

function performSearch() {
    var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value,
        targetTable = document.getElementById('dataTable');

    findRows(targetTable, 0, searchText);
}

document.getElementById("searchTerm").onkeyup = performSearch;
```

[working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLz7y4vx/2)

Comment: @User014019 Please see my updated answer, and the fiddle. If you don't add a button, then the search won't work if the user pastes the text into the search box.

Comment: I don't really understand. Wouldn't that just be more annoying for the user?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your problem is transversing the DOM. Here is how to loop through table rows:

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for(i = 0; i < trs.length; i++){
    //trs[i] is the current table row, .children[0] selects the first child
    console.log(trs[i].children[0]);
}
```

Then you can check the innerHtml for search terms using a regex or `indexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function processTable(tableId, searchTerm, colNumber, hideCallback, showCallBack) {

    var mySearchTerm = searchTerm || "",
        myTable = document.getElementById(tableId) || document.createElement("TABLE"),
        myRowsArray = getElements(null, "TR", myTable), //convert to array
        myRowsArrayLength = myRowsArray.length;

    var index = 0;
    for (var i = myRowsArrayLength; --i;) {
        var myTempRowElement = myRowsArray[i],
            myTempColArray = getElements(null, "TD", myTempRowElement),
            myTempCol = (myTempColArray.length > 0 ? myTempColArray[colNumber - 1] : document.createElement("TD")),
            myText = getText(myTempCol);
        if (myText === mySearchTerm) {
            showCallBack(myTempRowElement);
        }
        else {
            hideCallback(myTempRowElement);
        }
    }
};

function init() {

    var myHandler = function (e) {
        var myTermEl = document.getElementById("searchTerm"),
            myTextContent = getText(myTermEl) || myTermEl.value || "";

        processTable("dataTable", myTextContent, 1,
            function hideCallback(el) {
                el.style.display = 'none';
            },
            function showCallBack(el) {
                el.style.display = 'table-row';
            }
        );
    };

    myHandler();

    document.getElementById("searchTerm").onkeyup = myHandler;
    document.getElementById("searchTerm").onchange = myHandler;
    document.getElementById("searchTerm").onclick = myHandler;
};

(function () {
    if (this.addEventListener) {
        this.addEventListener("load", init, false)
    }
    else {
        window.onload = init;
    }
}());
var isClassMember = function (element, classname) {
    var classes = element.className;
    if (!classes) {
        return false;
    };
    if (classes == classname) {
        return true;
    };
    var whitespace = /\s+/;
    if (!whitespace.test(classes)) {
        return false;
    };
    var c = classes.split(whitespace);
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i] == classname) {
            return true;
        };
    };
    return false;
};
var getElements = function (classname, tagname, root, firstFlag, depth) {
    if (!root) {
        root = document;
    }
    else {
        if (typeof root == "string") {
            root = document.getElementById(root);
        };
    };
    if (!tagname) {
        tagname = "*";
    };
    if (depth) {
        var maxRecursion = depth;
        var all = (function getChildsElementsLevel(root, tagName, currentLevelNumber) {
            var result = [],
                currentLevelChilds = (function getLevelChilds(root, tagName) {
                    var result = [];
                    var children = root.firstChild;
                    do {
                        if (children.nodeName == tagName) {
                            result.push(children);
                        };
                    } while (children = children.nextSibling);
                    return result;
                })(root, tagName),
                currentLevelChildsLength = currentLevelChilds.length,
                nextLevelNumber = ++currentLevelNumber;

            for (var f = currentLevelChildsLength; f--;) {

                var currentEl = currentLevelChilds[f];
                result.push(currentEl);
                if (nextLevelNumber < maxRecursion) {
                    result.concat(getChildsElementsLevel(currentEl, tagName, nextLevelNumber));
                }
            }
            return result;
        })(root, tagname, 0);
    }
    else {
        var all = root.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
    }
    if (!classname) {
        return all;
    };
    var elements = [],
        allLength = all.length,
        isMyClass = isClassMember;
    if (firstFlag) {
        for (var i = 0; i < allLength; i++) {

            var element = all[i];
            if (isMyClass(element, classname)) {
                return element;
            };
        };
    }
    else {
        for (var i = allLength; i--;) {

            var element = all[i];
            if (isMyClass(element, classname)) {
                elements.push(element);
            };
        };
    }

    return elements;
};
var getText = function (n) {
    function getStrings(n, strings) {

        if (n.nodeType == 3 /* Node.TEXT_NODE */) {
            strings.push(n.data);
        }
        else {
            if (n.nodeType == 1 /* Node.ELEMENT_NODE */) {
                for (var m = n.firstChild; m != null; m = m.nextSibling) {
                    getStrings(m, strings);
                };
            };
        };
    };
    var strings = [];
    getStrings(n, strings);
    return strings.join("");
};
```

Comment: Would you mind telling us what this massive chunk of code accomplishes?

Comment: I'm a little tweaked the code. All you need to do is to find the event and start processing function processTable.

Comment: can you give us some running example?